# Query in UserRepository which extends JPA

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa

I've been trying to get a user by username and password from my MySQL database and I keep getting these errors.

```
    @Query("select u from User where u.username = :username and u.password = :password")
public User findByUsernameAndPassword(@Param("username") String username,
                               @Param("password") String password);
```

Errors:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Unable to resolve path [u.username], unexpected token [u] [select u from com.Rest.GolfMax.API.Users.User where u.username = :username and u.password = :password]
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Unable to resolve path [u.username], unexpected token [u]
```

Comment: your sql query itself is wrong, try to first execute the query in the sql cli and then u update it according to jpa

Comment: @ArunSai That's not SQL but JPQL.

Comment: @JensSchauder yes, it's jpql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a small error in the syntax, I fixed it:

```
@Query("select u from User u where u.username = :username and u.password = :password")
```

If you don't encode the password, then this will work for you.  But I would recommend using Spring Security for these purposes.

Comment: I am just trying to have the API work before implementing Spring security. Thanks for the answer though! It worked